# how do you parse data from resource folder in main activity class to a data class in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, arrays, parsing

I'm creating a android app that parses data from an xml file located in the resources folder in the main activity class, I am then storing this data to arrays and trying to send this data to a data class where the arrays of parsed data are assigned an object array. I'm getting null pointers but no errors. I'm new to this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Here is my MainActivity class:

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private String[] names;
    private String[] positions;
    private String[] abouts;
    private String[] links;
    private String[] images;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         //Parse data from file
         xmlParsed();


        final PlayerData team = new PlayerData();

        ListView list =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.MainList);

            // Binding resources Array to ListAdapter
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item,     R.id.label,team.playerNames());

    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

         Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ImageActivity.class);

            Player play = team.getPlayer(position);

            Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();
                bundle1.putSerializable("player",play);
                intent.putExtras(bundle1);

                        startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_OK);
          }
     }); 

    }

public void xmlParsed(){

    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.players);

    //String file = "res/raw/players.xml";
    //InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(file);

    DocumentBuilder docBuilder=null;

        try {
                docBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        }catch (ParserConfigurationException e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            Document document = docBuilder.parse(is);

            //names
         NodeList nameList = document.getElementsByTagName("name");
         names= new String[nameList.getLength()];

         for(int i=0; i<nameList.getLength();i++)
          {
             names[i]= nameList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue(); 
          }

          //positions
          NodeList positionList = document.getElementsByTagName("position");
          positions= new String[positionList.getLength()];
          for(int i=0; i<positionList.getLength();i++)
        {   
            positions[i]= positionList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue(); 
            }

         //images
         NodeList imageList = document.getElementsByTagName("image");
         images= new String [imageList.getLength()];
         for(int i=0; i<imageList.getLength();i++)
         {
              images[i]= imageList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue(); 

         }

         //abouts 
         NodeList aboutList = document.getElementsByTagName("about");
         abouts= new String[aboutList.getLength()];
         for(int i=0; i<aboutList.getLength();i++)  
         {
            abouts[i]= aboutList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue(); 
         }

         //links
        NodeList linkList = document.getElementsByTagName("about");
         links= new String[linkList.getLength()];
         for(int i=0; i<linkList.getLength();i++)           
         {          
            links[i]= linkList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue(); 

         }

        }catch (SAXException e) {
                System.out.println("Wrong XML file structure: " + e.getMessage());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("I/O exeption: " + e.getMessage());

        }
    }

    {

public String[] getNames() { return names; } 

public void setNames(String[] names) {this.names=names;}

public String[] getPosition(){return positions;}

public String[] getPositions() {return positions;}

public void setPositions(String[] positions) {this.positions = positions;}

public String[] getAbouts() {return abouts;}

public void setAbouts(String[] abouts) {this.abouts = abouts;}

public String[] getLinks() {return links;}

public void setLinks(String[] links) {this.links = links;}

public String[] getImages() {return images;}

public void setImages(String[] images) {this.images = images;}

//public String getElement(int location) { return images[location]; } 

//public void setElement(int value, int location) { imageIds[location] = value;}

}
```

And here is my data class:

```
public class PlayerData extends Player {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;



    MainActivity pullXml =new MainActivity();
    String[] namesArray= pullXml.getNames();
    String[] positionsArray= pullXml.getPositions();
    String[] aboutsArray=pullXml.getAbouts();
    String[] linksArray=pullXml.getLinks();
    String[] imagesArray=pullXml.getImages();

Player[]team= {
new Player(namesArray[0],positionsArray[0],aboutsArray[0],linksArray[0],0),
new Player(namesArray[1],positionsArray[1],aboutsArray[1],linksArray[1],1), 
new Player(namesArray[2],positionsArray[1],aboutsArray[1],linksArray[1],1),     
new Player(namesArray[3],positionsArray[1],aboutsArray[1],linksArray[1],1),     
new Player(namesArray[4],positionsArray[1],aboutsArray[1],linksArray[1],1),     
new Player(namesArray[5],positionsArray[1],aboutsArray[1],linksArray[1],1),     
new Player(namesArray[6],positionsArray[1],aboutsArray[1],linksArray[1],1),     
new Player(namesArray[7],positionsArray[1],aboutsArray[1],linksArray[1],1),     
new Player(namesArray[8],positionsArray[1],aboutsArray[1],linksArray[1],1),     
};

    String [] playerNames(){
        String [] names = new String[team.length];

        for(int i=0;i<team.length;i++){
            names[i]=team[i].getPlayerName();
        }

        return names;
    }

    String playerName(int i){return team[i].getPlayerName();}

    String playerPosition(int i){return team[i].getPlayerPosition();}

    int playerPic(int i){return team[i].getPlayerImage();}

    String playerInfo(int i){return team[i].getPlayerInfo();}

    String playerURL(int i){return team[i].getPlayerURL();}

    Player getPlayer(int i){return team[i];}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `getAssets()` method of the class Resources. It will return a `AssetManager` using which, you could significantly reduce the effort to accomplish this.

[Here is a link to the Docs.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getAssets%28%29)